# how to use setwebhook in telegram?

Tags: certificate, telegram, telegram-bot

Hello I'm creating a bot in telegram. I send a http request:

https://api.telegram.org/bot(mytoken)/setWebhook?url=https://mywebpagetorespondtobot

and I receive this:

`{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}`

but It doesn't work.I mean telegram doesn't send updates to the server.
Is this because I didn't upload my certificate?how should I do that then?

Comment: how do you recive updates?

Comment: When I delete the webhook, getUpdates() works fine

Comment: do you use self-Signed certificate?

Answer (score 12):

Check the status of your updates here:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botYOUR_TOKEN/getWebhookInfo
```

It will tell you about any errors. Should you **not**  see any problems here the issue is to be found somewhere in your script. Make sure to handle incoming updates correctly.

It might be a problem with self-signed certificate. It needs to be uploaded via setWebhook method first as described [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed/). Or try a more extensive guide [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks).

Comment: I deleted the webhook and getUpdates() worked fine.Maby the problem is with the certificate.I read the link but I don't know how to generate and send the pem file

Answer (score 6):

I changed the setwebhook url to a  and it worked.it seems that it doesn't work with a wabepage url.
https://api.telegram.org/bot(mytoken)/setWebhook?url=https://mywebpagetorespondtobot/mymethod ' (the WebMethod)

Answer (score 6):

It's means what your public key incorrect.

You may check it by url https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getWebhookInfo
after setting

When i sent incorrect public key - i receive

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":6}}
```

but if i sent correct public key, i receive:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"mycorrecturl.com","has_custom_certificate":true,"pending_update_count":6,"last_error_date":1506772578,"last_error_message":"SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}","max_connections":40}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. BotFather -> Bot list -> API Token -> Revoke current token
2. https://api.telegram.org/bot(New token)/setWebhook?url=https://myweb...
   Done)